# Self Checking Codes

Tags: python-3.x, function

I'm new to programming and is currently self teaching my self on how to code. If I'm being honest I don't even know if this is the right place to post these kind of question.

But, I just made an men_macro() function that calculate men calories.

```
def men_macro(height, weight, age, activity_level, gender='Male'):
''' Initializing the activity_level '''
active_level = {'Sedentary': 1.2,
                'Lightly Active': 1.375,
                'Moderately Active': 1.55,
                'Very Active': 1.725,
                'Extremely Active': 1.9}

# Creating men Macro Formula using Mifflin-St Jeor Equation
macro = ((10 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age) + 5)

# Check if activity_level argument is in the active_level dictonary
for key, value in active_level.items():
    if activity_level == key:
        return macro * value
```

The function works, and I've gotten my macro just fine.

What's your guys opinion on the code, just want your guys opinion and there's anything I need to improve on.

Comment: If this code is already working and you are asking someone to review your code, check out this other StackExchange site: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Make sure to follow their [how-to-ask guide](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is for asking *specific* questions and solving *specific* problems.

Comment: @GinoMempin, thanks I will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

I think active_level is better to take out of function - it's independent of local variables. 
The last block I'do redo as following:

```
if activity_level in active_level:
    return macro*active_level[activity_level]
```